# ApiPlatform - watch sql query

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I want to understand how apiplatform works and for this have to understand sql query, how i can watch this ?

i dont see anythings about this in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the profiler for debug SQL query from API Platform.

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform/profiler

Comment: thank you, it was perfect, you can have, query and explaination of query.